# Jquery sliding/animated counter (countup) or customers served counter

Tags: jquery, counter, animated

I am looking for a countup counter which has sliding numbers. The counter is for calls attended and customers served, emails replied. I am looking for a plugin similar to the one on this page: http://codemyconcept.com. I have found alot of examples which just changes number, i need one which has some animatioon and the numbers slide up rather than changing every second. Check out the page to view the example in motion.

Thanks

Comment: This is a programming question and answer site, not a personal shopping service. Unless you have a specific question about a programming difficulty that you're having, I'm afraid I'll vote to close as 'off-topic.' Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Did you even look at the source code from the page you linked to? It took me less than a minute to open the page and check the source to see what JS files are included, at which point it was obvious that it uses jQuery, and specifically the jOdometer plugin found here: http://www.frontendmatters.com/projects/jquery-plugins/jodometer/.

Implementing a counter using that plugin I leave as an exercise for the OP...

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this, I developed it myself and its easy to extend functionality if you need to:

http://kcounter.kudoslabs.co.uk/